# Rails How to escape and display the contents of a rendered view

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, view

I am trying to show a rails view file in a textarea.  the view file contains a bunch of HTML, which I want to escape so that it does not interfere with on page html.  here is an example:

```
In this view we are going to display the contents of a partial
<textarea>
<%= html_escape render('partial') %>
</textarea>
```

and in partial.html.erb I would have

```
Hello this is partial.html.erb and this is a 
<textarea>textarea</textarea>  blah blah blah.
```

The problem is: the textarea in partial.html is breaking the textarea in the first view because it is not being html_escaped.  How do I property escape and display the contents of the partial inside the textarea?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you try using

```
<%= CGI.escapeHTML render('partial') %>
```

Comment: Just found this: <%= CGI.escapeHTML(render('partial')) %>, does that might solve it? you could also try use CGI.escapeHTML with render_to_string.

Answer (score 1):

Try [`render_to_string`](http://rails.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Base.html#M000465) in your controller and then using `html_escape` on the resulting string.

Comment: nope, still does not work.  the html_escape fails to escape whats returned by render_to_string

Answer (score 0):

Ok - I figured it out.  You basically have to call render twice.  The first time is to render the file and the second time is to escape that rendered file.  This is ugly!

```
<%= render :text => render("partial") %>
```

I'd be interested to see if anyone else has any other ways to escape partial.html.

Answer (score 0):

Hello 
I see it was long time ago , but here what I suggest :
 ... sanitize instance.yourtext %>
I found the 'sanitize' helper in the "Agile web design with Ruby on Rails" by S.Ruby , D.Thomas and D.Hansson .
Hope it helps...

Answer (score 0):

*EDITED*
By default in Rails, text_area escapes HTML to avoid malicious script embedding. Use a form helper to create your `<textarea>`

```
<%= f.text_area :model_attribute %>
```

Note: If you  one needs to see the raw HTML in the text area, just include the :escape parameter and set the value to false to disable HTML escaping.

```
<%= f.text_area :model_attribute, escape: false %>
```

Citation: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-text_area_tag

If using this feature, I recommend validating or eliminating the script tag from the submitted value if the source is not trusted or open to the public.